# React router not rendering JSX components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

React router not rendering my JSX. It doesn't display the content of the components. It renders a blank page.

Below is my root component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/Home'
import About from './components/About'
import Contact from './components/Contact'

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="App">
                    <Navbar />
                    <Route path="/Home" Component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/About" Component={About} />
                    <Route path="/Contact" Component={Contact} />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

Comment: `react-dom` is responsible for rendering your React components, particularly the `render` method. Could you post where you are calling the `render` method? Also, which route renders the blank page? If you are on the `/` route, it will only render your `Navbar` component.

Comment: hi! thanks for reaching out. i don't quite understand your question. can you please go through the code one more time?  the only page i have left are the ones that i've imported at the top of my code. thank you

Comment: You should replace "Component" with "component" inside your Route and, as mentioned by Khan, add a default route to "/", so the first time your page loads you see something.

Answer (score 1):

If your domain is, for example, "site.com", you only have routes for "site.com/Home", "site.com/About" and "site.com/Contact", so when your routing is empty, it's only normal that nothing is going to show up.

If you add a route to your root domain after all your routes, something should show up instead of nothing.

For example, try adding this after all your other routes;

```
<Route path='/' component={Home} exact/>
```

Also, your props should be named "component" instead of "Component" for your Route component.

I tried replicating your scenario here:

[image: Edit interesting-mclaren-m6h9g]

You can edit the code and make your own changes as you learn about routing. I truly think though that you were not being able to see your JSX because of the first uppercase letter in your Route props being "Component" instead of "component".